# python pandas: how to switch x-axis with y-axis for a line graph

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, linegraph

I have a problem with creating a line graph. I need to switch the x-axis with y-axis.

**My idea is to visualize the Branch (F1, F2, F3, F4) on the y-axis and the weeks from 1-100 on the x-axis**

If you have any idea how to do this please comment :) Thanks!

My data looks like that:
[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sYCW.png)

My code:

```
data.set_index('Branch').plot()
plt.show()
```

[after I plot my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlGtJ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try transposing the DataFrame prior to plotting:

```
data.set_index('Branch').T.plot()
plt.show()
```

Comment: thank you so much, this solved my problem.